# Django, What's the best ,fastest way to get only first and last element from something, Customer.objects.xxxx

Tags: python, django, django-models

Django, What's the best ,fastest way to get only first and last element from something, Customer.objects.xxxx such filter, value_list or ...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Probably most pythonic way:

```
myset = Customer.objects.filter(<something>).order_by(<something>)
first, last = myset[0], myset.reverse()[0]
```

Comment: didn't know you could use .reverse() on a queryset, nice!

Comment: using indexing directly is really pythonic ?

Answer (score 4):

> What's the best ,fastest way to get only first and last

Let us see.

```
customers = Customer.objects.filter(**conditions)
first = customers.order_by('id')[0]
last = customers.latest('id')
```

Of course *if* you can come up with an SQL query to do this it could be executed using the [`raw()`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/#django.db.models.Manager.raw) method.

```
query = "<your query to get first and last>"
Customer.objects.raw(query)
```

Comment: You don't have to write query twice: myset = Customer.objects.filter(**conditions); first = myset.order_by('id')[0]; last = myset..latest('id')

Answer (score 0):

I am not totally familiar with the inner workings of django but I would assume the fastest way to do this would be:

```
elements = Customer.objects.filter(<something>)
first_element = elements[0]
last_element = elements[-1]
```

Comment: `last_element = elements[-1]` will raise an error; negative indexing is not supported by Querysets. Which makes sense if you think of the SQL issued (using `LIMIT` clause)

Comment: Defining first/last_element is also of course probably not necessary.