# Make a query to get the latest objects, excluding duplicates of obj.x

Tags: python, django

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Django, What's the best ,fastest way to get only first and last element from something, Customer.objects.xxxx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3664708/django-whats-the-best-fastest-way-to-get-only-first-and-last-element-from-som)

Hmm this is hard to explain, but this is what's happening..

I have a model A that has x and date

There are multiple A's with the same x and different dates.

From:

```
A.x = 1 (newest)
A.x = 1
A.x = 1 (oldest)
A.x = 2
```

I want to get only the newest of each x, in this case the first one, and the last one, excluding the older x=1 duplicates.

I've thought of doing some nasty loops or using itertools, but I'm not sure what's the best way to achieve this.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is a one-liner with `itertools.groupby` (possibly with a `i[0] for i in itertools.groupby…` expression wrapped around it) too nasty?

Answer (score 0):

Starting Django 1.4 the .distinct() queryset API accepts field parameters

So I guess you can do something like this

```
Queryset.order_by('-date').distinct('field')
```

You can read more about it [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/models/querysets/#distinct).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`latest()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#latest) queryset method.  It's basically the same as using `.order_by()[0]`.

This is nice since, I always forget if I need to use the "-" or not when using `order_by()` with dates.

```
latest_object = Model.objects.latest("date/datetime fieldname")
```